# Where is the flickr Carousel/Slideshow "hero" available?

Tags: javascript, yui, carousel, flickr

I was looking at flickr and noticed their carousel at the top and how smoothly it operated. Upon inspecting it, it shows "yui" but I don't see it anywhere in the YUI list of items.

http://www.flickr.com/#yui_3_5_1_3_1354482071640_111

Does anyone know what elements specifically from YUI the carousel is made from, and where they're available?

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following are conclusions I'm reaching based on what I can tell from the HTML and minified JS source.

The Flickr carousel is written with very little YUI code and without using any complex component besides the [transition](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/transition/) module. Transition is used to provide a fallback for animations in older browsers. It's very smooth because it's using CSS transitions, in particular using `translate3d()` which works really well for moving images in one direction.

Like Quinn mentions, there's the Gallery Carousel widget. Lately I'm using [ScrollView](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/scrollview/) + [ScrollViewPaginator](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/scrollview/#paginator) and disabling drag events in non-touch devices. I like this approach because it feels like the typical carousel, but it also supports flicking through the images/pages with gestures on touch devices.

Answer (score 0):

you can build it very easily using the YUI Gallery Carousel [YUI Gallery Carousel](http://yuilibrary.com/gallery/show/carousel)